# WebTestCase does not autoload @Route annotation

Tags: testing, symfony, annotations, routes

It seams that `@Route` annotations are not working when doing functional tests with `WebTestCase` class.

My controller looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace Foo\ShopBundle\Controller;

use Foo\ShopBundle\Entity\Cart;
use Foo\ShopBundle\Entity\ProductInterface;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

/**
 * @Route("cart")
 */
class CartController extends Controller
{
    const CART_ID = 'cart_id';

    /**
     * @Route("/")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return array('cart' => $this->getCart($this->getCurrentUserName(), $this->getCurrentSessionId()));
    }

    ...

?>
```

This works fine if I call the controller from my browser. But calling the same URL in a `WebTestCase` yields the following excetpion:

```
Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException : [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route" in class Foo\ShopBundle\Controller\CartController does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
#0 /Users/ernst/Source/php/cinergy/shop/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/DocParser.php(597): Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException::semanticalError('The annotation ...')
#1 /Users/ernst/Source/php/cinergy/shop/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/DocParser.php(533): Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocParser->Annotation()
#2 /Users/ernst/Source/php/cinergy/shop/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/DocParser.php(297): Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocParser->Annotations()
#3 /Users/ernst/Source/php/cinergy/shop/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationReader.php(151): Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocParser->parse('/**? * @Route("...', 'class Foo\S...')
#4 /Users/ernst/Source/php/cinergy/shop/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/FileCacheReader.php(90): Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader->getClassAnnotations(Object(ReflectionClass))
#5 /Users/ernst/Source/php/cinergy/shop/vendor/jms/di-extra-bundle/JMS/DiExtraBundle/Metadata/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php(65): Doctrine\Common\Annotations\FileCacheReader->getClassAnnotations(Object(ReflectionClass))
#6 /Users/ernst/Source/php/cinergy/shop/vendor/jms/metadata/src/Metadata/Driver/LazyLoadingDriver.php(20): JMS\DiExtraBundle\Metadata\Driver\AnnotationDriver->loadMetadataForClass(Object(ReflectionClass))
#7 /Users/ernst/Source/php/cinergy/shop/vendor/jms/metadata/src/Metadata/MetadataFactory.php(77): Metadata\Driver\LazyLoadingDriver->loadMetadataForClass(Object(ReflectionClass))
#8 /Users/ernst/Source/php/cinergy/shop/vendor/jms/di-extra-bundle/JMS/DiExtraBundle/HttpKernel/ControllerResolver.php(84): Metadata\MetadataFactory->getMetadataForClass('Foo\ShopBun...')
#9 /Users/ernst/Source/php/cinergy/shop/vendor/jms/di-extra-bundle/JMS/DiExtraBundle/HttpKernel/ControllerInjectorsWarmer.php(31): JMS\DiExtraBundle\HttpKernel\ControllerResolver->createInjector('Foo\ShopBun...')
#10 /Users/ernst/Source/php/cinergy/shop/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/CacheWarmer/CacheWarmerAggregate.php(47): JMS\DiExtraBundle\HttpKernel\ControllerInjectorsWarmer->warmUp('/Users/ernst/So...')
#11 /Users/ernst/Source/php/cinergy/shop/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(595): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\CacheWarmer\CacheWarmerAggregate->warmUp('/Users/ernst/So...')
#12 /Users/ernst/Source/php/cinergy/shop/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(133): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer()
#13 /Users/ernst/Source/php/cinergy/shop/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/WebTestCase.php(43): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()
#14 /Users/ernst/Source/php/cinergy/shop/src/Foo/ShopBundle/Tests/Controller/CartControllerFunctionalTest.php(19): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase::createClient()
#15 [internal function]: Foo\ShopBundle\Tests\Controller\CartControllerFunctionalTest->testIndexAction()
#16 /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/lib/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php(967): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(Foo\ShopBundle\Tests\Controller\CartControllerFunctionalTest), Array)
#17 /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/lib/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php(825): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest()
#18 /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/lib/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestResult.php(649): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare()
#19 /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/lib/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php(770): PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run(Object(Foo\ShopBundle\Tests\Controller\CartControllerFunctionalTest))
#20 /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/lib/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php(776): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))
#21 /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/lib/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php(746): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->runTest(Object(Foo\ShopBundle\Tests\Controller\CartControllerFunctionalTest), Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))
#22 /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/lib/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php(706): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult), false, Array, Array, false)
#23 /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/lib/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php(325): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult), false, Array, Array, false)
#24 /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/lib/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php(177): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite), Array)
#25 /private/var/folders/kc/ylyxk45170z_g5h6c2_vr0_00000gp/T/ide-phpunit.php(102): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
#26 /private/var/folders/kc/ylyxk45170z_g5h6c2_vr0_00000gp/T/ide-phpunit.php(442): IDE_PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
#27 {main}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add this to your setUp() method (dont forget to define $vendorDir)

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
....
public function setUp()
{
    /** To make annotations work here */
    AnnotationRegistry::registerAutoloadNamespaces(array('Sensio\\Bundle\\FrameworkExtraBundle' => $vendorDir . '/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/'));
....
```

Comment: However I'm curious why this is necessary. WebTestCase is bootsrapping the whole AppKernel. Since the application is working fine from the browser, I would expect no differences here.

Comment: Had the same issue and i don't know why annotations are not work in test env as well as in browser. So have found this workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is quite old I want to add something:

Please go sure that you are always pointing to your phpunit.xml(.dist) file during testing.

That means:

```
# OK
phpunit -c app/ src/MyNamespace/Bundlee/MyBundle/Controller/MyControllerTest.php
```

will work.

However dropping `-c app` in the command will break the test runner as Symfony could not be booted as it should:

```
# ERROR
phpunit src/MyNamespace/Bundlee/MyBundle/Controller/MyControllerTest.php
```

In the latter case the autoloading could not be initialized normally and so Doctrine Annotations could not be registered properly too.

The mentioned "tweaks" in the setUp method are no more needed then!

Answer (score 1):

Check your phpunit.xml.dist file. Your bootstrap param should point to the file `./autoload.php` (assuming the file is in the Symfony app directory). 
If your bootstrap value is `../vendor/autoload.php` you're not registering 'loadClass'.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. Turned out I had the following in my phpunit.xml:

```
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         ...
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php">
```

Changing the value of `bootstrap` to `app/bootstrap.php.cache` solved the problem for me. The annotation loader is now being registered correctly.

If you take a look at https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.8/app/phpunit.xml.dist#L8, you'll see that the default Symfony application uses this file as it's PHPUnit bootstrap as well.

Note that my phpunit.xml is in the root of my project, not in the `app` directory. If the phpunit.xml file is in the `app` directory, you can simply use `bootstrap.php.cache`.